# Import file based on relative path in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, commonjs

I have such project structure:

```
- MyApp
`- firstFolder
 `- firstFile.js
`- secondFolder
 `- thirdFolder
  `- thirdFile.js
```

How can I import `firstFile.js` from `thirdFile.js`?

Something like `import myFunc from '../firstFolder/firstFile';` in `thirdFile.js`, doesn't work.

Comment: `import ../../firstFolder/firstFile.js;` or `import ./firstFolder/firstFile.js`

Comment: Have you tried '../../firstFolder/firstFile', since you need to go two dirs up?

Comment: @abc123 second answer doesn't work.

Comment: See https://levelup.gitconnected.com/understand-and-configure-absolute-import-paths-in-javascript-5cde3be2630d

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Description

There are multiple pathing options, I'll describe a couple below.

### Folder Structure

```bash
MyApp
├── firstFolder
│   └── firstFile.js
└── secondFolder
    └── thirdFolder
        └── thirdFile.js
```

### Relative path

Here we will `import` the `firstFile` from our `thirdFile`.

`../` will go back 1 folder, this is why we go back two folders:

```
import myFunc from '../../firstFolder/firstFile'
```

So `..` takes us back to `secondFolder` then we need to go back one more folder `..` into the `MyApp` folder.  Now we can traverse forward into `firstFolder` then point to `firstFile`.

or `./` - this is the present working directory (pwd), which will be `thirdFolder` from here we will need to go back 2 directories or `../..`

```
import myFunc from './../../firstFolder/firstFile'
```

### Full path

*Since you didn't specify the full paths these are incomplete*

`/` - will start at the root directory of the Operating System

```
import myFunc from '/fullPathtoProject/MyApp/firstFolder/firstFile'
```

`~/` this is the current users home directory

```
import myFunc from '~/pathFromHomeDirectory/MyApp/firstFolder/firstFile'
```

Comment: @YuriyN. try `/` instead of `./` that is a nodejs reference

Comment: @YuriyN. k, then you'll need to use `../`, can you try `~/`, also are you just using these as the first character? can you post the full strings?

Comment: I'll try all, and then write results, but I can say now, with certainty, that second variant doesn't work, it relates to current folder.

Comment: Nothing work, I tried all these cases, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The example `import myFunc from ./firstFolder/firstFile.js` is wrong. Single `.` references the current directory.

Comment: Using just a slash prefix rather than `./` works for me with a modern browser. The tilda variant does not. So I think that as is, together with the previous comment this answer is too wrong to be here.

Comment: @matanster updated answers with more context; let me know if you desire more.

Comment: @MattYoon you are correct

Comment: @YuriiN. Please link to questions or give more detail for assistance.

Comment: The paths must be quoted for anything to work!  Use `import myFunc from '../../firstFolder/firstFile'` with single `'` or double quotes `"`.

Comment: @AkseliPalén thanks, updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

in ES5:

You should use two '..' to back 1 folder level

```
var myFunc = require('../../firstFolder/firstFile');
```

ES6 (ecmascript6):

```
import myFunc from '../../firstFolder/firstFile';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But abc123 was answered it first.

Answer (score 3):

If you use webpack you can tweak the loader to search for files relative to your base directory. Change your `webpack.config.js` to this

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve('./'),
    path.resolve('./node_modules')
  ]
},
```

or, if your sources are all relative to `./src`, use `path.resolve('./src')`. If you want to be more specific you can also take a look at `resolve.alias` (see the webpack docs here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

BTW: I'm using next.js in my application, which has its own webpack config, but you can modify it if you put something like

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = ({
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.resolve.modules.push( path.resolve('./') )
        return config
    },
})
```

into your `next.config.js`, in order to modify the default one.

Answer (score 2):

use=>

```
import myFunc from '../../firstFolder/firstFile';
```

or

```
import * as myFunc from '../../firstFolder/firstFile';
```