# Unable to Initialize firebase in Vue web app

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use a Cloud Firestore database collection in my vue app. However, when I run npm run serve to load my vue app in the browser, I am met with an error:

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./firebaseInit in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

I've made sure to install `npm install firebase --save`, but I am still getting the above error.

I have a two files that setup firebase in my root directory, `firebaseConfig.js` that holds my app settings and `firebaseInit.js` that imports and exports firebase throughout my app. Below is a screenshot of my directory structure.

[image: Directory structure]

```js
// firebaseConfig.js
export default {
  //mock data
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDOCAbC123dEf456GhI789jKl01-MnO",
  authDomain: "myapp-project-123.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myapp-project-123.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myapp-project-123",
  storageBucket: "myapp-project-123.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "65211879809",
  appId: "1:65211879909:web:3ae38ef1cdcb2e01fe5f0c",
}
```

```js
// firebaseInit.js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

When I try and import firebaseInit.js in my app.js file, I am met with the error stated above.

```html
// App.vue
... <template>
<script>
import db from './firebaseInit'

</script>
```

I've tried looking into the docs and registering the config files in App.vue, but that did not work.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the directory containing these files?

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the directory @Phil

Comment: Assuming `App.vue` is in your `src` directory, you want `import db from "../firebaseInit.js"`. Personally though, I'd move those scripts into `src`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import file based on relative path in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209645/import-file-based-on-relative-path-in-javascript)

Comment: Moving the two firebase scripts into the ````src```` directory solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to
`firebaseInit.js`

```
export default const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
```

I had a similar problem. I also consolidated the 2 files into one file called firebaseApp.js which looks like this

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDoAX0RM_eB_Zv7_P3ENJZOe97jaN5-JNE",
    authDomain: "vuefs-prod-trav.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "vuefs-prod-trav",
    storageBucket: "vuefs-prod-trav.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "378644247244",
    appId: "1:378644247244:web:1a06b2e6c30c5ac2e54869",
    measurementId: "G-ZVGYPK8YRX"
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
var db = firebase.firestore()
export default db
```

Finally, import it as:
`import db from './firebaseApp'` inside your `<script>` of `example.vue` file.

Hope this helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Phil in the comments you could either import the script by using

```
import db from "../firebaseInit.js"
```

with the `../` indicating that your are importing from a top level directory, or you could place the scripts in the same `src` folder and keep the import as is.